# Drawing mode, make cursor visible?

Tags: grease-pencil, draw-mode

I tried the drawing mode with grease pencil but it's nigh impossible to draw anything since the cursor is almost invincible due to its size and I have massive neck pain now since I have to put my nose on my display to even see the cursor. Does anyone know a method to make this cursor more visible? Could not find anything in preference.

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: not sure why you need a screenshot for but sure.